# How can I lock my stolen iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Last night my iPhone 5 (32 GB) was stolen.

How can I lock it so that the person won't be able to use it anymore?

Comment: You know your number! just try calling it, sometimes there are nice people and will return it.

Answer (score 3):

If you had "Find my iPhone" enabled on your stolen phone, you can log into icloud.com with your AppleID and lock/purge the phone from there.

If you haven't enabled that option **or if the phone is not connected to the internet** there is no way to access the phone and purge its content.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have "Find my iPhone" installed, alternatively call to your service provider (if the phone is on contract so they've the details). Some mobile companies can lock your phone with immediately effect over the phone.